# Detect email client using HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to adjust the content of an HTML email based on the client which is being used to read the email (along with an option to default it to a generic content).

Is it possible using just HTML and CSS (since js will not work with HTML emails) to achieve this ?

I looked for possible ways to do this and found that conditional HTML like  can be used to check if client is outlook / lotus.

However, I also want to add checks for gmail and apple mail.

Is it possible using 'media' tags in CSS ?

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Do you mean how to check if they use Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, etc.?

Comment: Lots of good info here: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/, also here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: what you are trying to do is similar to browser sniffing, which is frowned upon, browsers lie ( boy do they lie?!) and just plain useless. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp for reference

Comment: Biggest problem you will face is the inconsistant CSS support in email clients

Answer (score 1):

Conditional HTML is your best bet to check against various email clients. It really depends on the email client itself, for example, Apple Mail is pretty forgiving with many CSS properties, but GMAIL strips out all CSS in the head. It's a balancing act! Check out caniuse.com to see which properties you can and can't use in email :)

Comment: Any advice on how to do this?